# itext pdf header

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

i am creating one pdf output using iText 5.0.5.
I am reading the data in the form of bytes from database and then adding it to the document using HTMLWorker to generate pdf.
BUt i am not able to add header on each paage for that pdf document.
please help.

Answer (score 2):

1) The latest iText is 5.0.6.

2) To create a page header and footer, you need to use the `PdfPageEvent` interface.  This is generally done by deriving from [`PdfPageEventHelper`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html), and overriding just the methods you need.

In the `PdfPageEvent`, you *must* draw to the PDF using a `PdfContentByte`.  The good news is that you can use a `ColumnText` to add aligned text into a given bounding box, and it'll handle line breaks for you.

```
public class HeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
  private String headerStr, footerStr;
  private Rectangle hBox, fBox;
  public HeaderFooterPageEvent(String hStr, Rectangle _hBox, String fString, Rectangle _fBox) {
    headerStr = hStr;
    hBox = _hBox;
    footerStr = fStr;
    fBox = _fBox;
  }

  public onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc) {
    // draw the header text.
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
      Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, headerStr, hBox.getRight(), hBox.getTop, 0);

    // draw the footer text.
   ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
      Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, footerStr, fBox.getRight(), fBox.getTop, 0);
  }
}
```

This won't work so well if your header & footer are in HTML.  For that you'll have to do some round-about hackery.

1) Create a new Document/PdfWriter with page margins matching the size (height & width) of your header.
2) Render all the header HTML into that page.
3) save the pdf.
4) Import that PDF page into your other document, and draw it thusly:

```
public onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(headerPDFPath);
  PdfImportedPage headerPageImport = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1); // 1 -> first page
  PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
  cb.addTemplate(headerPageImport, hBox.bottom(), hBox.left());
}
```